# Win32 Command Prompt Input Buffer not catching keypress

Tags: windows, key, buffer

I'm trying to write a DOS game using the Windows Command Prompt. I have my simplified sourcecode here:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE hStdin;
VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD);

int main(VOID) {
    DWORD cNumRead, fdwMode, i;
    INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128];
    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    while(true) {
        ReadConsoleInput(hStdin, irInBuf, 128, &cNumRead);

        for (i = 0; i < cNumRead; i++) {
            switch(irInBuf[i].EventType) {
                case KEY_EVENT:
                    KeyEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.KeyEvent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

VOID KeyEventProc(KEY_EVENT_RECORD ker) {
    if(ker.bKeyDown) {}
    else printf("key released\n");
}
```

The problem is that when multiple buttons are pressed in certain combinations they no longer seem to register!

For instance, run this program and press a, then let go. It will tell you that you let go of a button.

Now press j, k, and l. When you let go of any of these buttons it will let you know

NOW press j, k, l, and i. When you let go of i it will no long register that a button has been released!!! o.0

HOWEVER if you press j, k, l, and d then release d it will let you know. So it doesn't seem to be a 'maximum depressed states' issue since it can handle all 4 when you press those letters.

Now if you press j, k, l, i, and then d and let go of d it will not let you know that a button has been released. So it seems that certain letters mess stuff up.

I'm so very confused and I would greatly appreciate any help anyone is willing to give.

My goal is to be able to check for any combination of button presses, even if the player presses all buttons at once (flip their keyboard over and press everything at once) I want to be able to check for that.

If anyone has a better way of doing this within the windows api I'm open for suggestions

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of your keyboard hardware. Keyboards with limited [rollover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29) support will typically start misbehaving once you get more than 2 keys pressed at a time.

Comment: Thats not the case, using direct access to the keyboard hardware I can detect any keypresses. The difference is I want to do it within windows architecture

Comment: It would seem that there is a limitation on my hardware lol. Thanks for pointing that out... shucks...

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck with [GetKeyboardState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  But it might not be possible at all.  Many keyboards aren't designed to keep track of an arbitrary number of simultaneously pressed keys.